# Implementation difference in Association , Aggregation and Composition using Objective C

Tags: iphone

What is the implementation difference in Aggregation, Assiocation and Composition .. To me , conceptually there is difference in Object Ownership and lifetime but how to implement them any Example consdier Objective C

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=17264

Comment: Look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992671/objecitive-c-is-aggregation-composition-used-for-deciding-if-strong-weak-refere